# Why does GCC copy this object without calling the move or copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am passing a movable object to a lambda-expression-cast-to-a-function-pointer, and it appears that somewhere along the line the program makes a bitwise copy of the object, without calling the copy or move constructor. This then causes resources to get double-freed because the "real" copy of the object doesn't know it's been moved out of.

A more detailed trace is after the MCVE code.

MCVE:

```
// Compiled and run with:
//    g++ -std=c++11 -ggdb bugtest.cpp -o bugtest && ./bugtest
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct movable
{
    vector<string> values;

    movable();
    ~movable();

    movable(movable &&);
    movable& operator=(movable &&);

    movable(const movable &) = delete;
    movable& operator=(const movable &) = delete;
};

movable::movable() {cout << this << " default-constructing" << endl;}

movable::~movable()
{
    cout << this << " destructing with       " << values.size() << " values:" << endl;
    for(size_t k = 0; k < values.size(); k++)
        cout << " " << values[k] << endl;
}

movable::movable(movable &&o)
{
    cout << this << " move-constructing with " << o.values.size() << " values from " << &o << endl;
    this->values = move(o.values);
    o.values.resize(0);
}
movable& movable::operator=(movable &&o)
{
    cout << this << " move-assigning         " << o.values.size() << " values from " << &o << endl;
    this->values = move(o.values);
    o.values.resize(0);
    return *this;
}

#if 1
movable (*lambdaFunc)(movable) = +[](movable m) -> movable {
    cout << &m << " used in lambda" << endl;
    return m;
};
#else
movable lambdaFuncImpl(movable m) {
    cout << &m << " used in global function" << endl;
    return m;
};
movable (*lambdaFunc)(movable) = lambdaFuncImpl;
#endif

struct task
{
    movable arg;
    movable result;
    void run()
    {
        result = lambdaFunc(move(arg));
    }
};

int main()
{
    task t;
    t.arg.values.emplace_back("TheValue");
    t.run();
}
```

G++ version:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
```

Output:

```
0x7fff57dcbe20 default-constructing   <-- t.arg
0x7fff57dcbe38 default-constructing   <-- t.result
0x7fff57dcbdc0 move-constructing with 1 values from 0x7fff57dcbe20
                                      ^-- argument to lambdaFunc
0x7fff57dcbd70 used in lambda         <-- HUH!? That's not the address of an object that was constructed!
                                      It seems to be a bitwise copy of 0x7fff57dcbdc0
0x7fff57dcbde0 move-constructing with 1 values from 0x7fff57dcbd70
                                      <-- return value; when we move out of ...70, this doesn't affect the real object ...c0
0x7fff57dcbe38 move-assigning         1 values from 0x7fff57dcbde0
                                      ^-- assigning to t.result
0x7fff57dcbde0 destructing with       0 values:
0x7fff57dcbdc0 destructing with       1 values:
 TheValue
                                      ^-- Uh oh, because of all the move assignments, ...c0 and ...38 are pointing to the same memory, which is now free
0x7fff57dcbe38 destructing with       1 values
Segmentation fault      (core dumped) <-- trying to print a string that is now freed
```

Changing `#if 1` to `#if 0` produces the expected output by avoiding the use of a lambda:

```
0x7ffe3b11b910 default-constructing   <-- t.arg
0x7ffe3b11b928 default-constructing   <-- t.result
0x7ffe3b11b8b0 move-constructing with 1 values from 0x7ffe3b11b910
0x7ffe3b11b8b0 used in global function<-- The same object that was just constructed
0x7ffe3b11b8d0 move-constructing with 1 values from 0x7ffe3b11b8b0
0x7ffe3b11b928 move-assigning         1 values from 0x7ffe3b11b8d0
0x7ffe3b11b8d0 destructing with       0 values:
                                      ^-- The values are not freed because this object was emptied when it was moved from.
0x7ffe3b11b8b0 destructing with       0 values:
0x7ffe3b11b928 destructing with       1 values:
 TheValue
0x7ffe3b11b910 destructing with       0 values:
```

What is wrong with this program?

Comment: could be [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Comment: I played with it on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NLzeTF3J90bBglFR). Since gcc 6.1 it works in both cases. For Clang 3.2 it generates illegal instructions (?).

Comment: BTW: I did also look at the assembly code to confirm GCC generated a bitwise copy, as opposed to passing a garbage pointer for example.

Comment: Sounds like already-fixed codegen problem, then.